# Typescript What is this ternary format doing in the function, it does not look right

Tags: typescript, default-value, ternary

Typescript.
Looking through a projects code I ran across some code written as such and I cannot track down if it is valid. If it is valid what is this doing because I don't see how what it would be defaulting to.

```
public someFn = function(arg ?: number): void {
  console.log(arg);
}
```

It is unclear what is going on with arg.
It is unclear what : void is doing here.

Please explain if you can.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not JavaScript.

Comment: it's just saying arg is an optional argument, it's not a ternary operator

Comment: @bryan60 so in Typescript use of the ?: together means optional?

Comment: putting ? after a function argument marks it as optional. the : is just the delimiter for typing the argument

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the correction. It explains also why I could not find the reference. Too many files I have open and thought this was a js file.

Comment: @bryan60 thanks for the input. much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is Typescript. The `?` indicates an optional variable during static type checking.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

If the variable is unspecified in the function call it defaults to `undefined`.

Comment: But `public someFn` throws error declaration or `statement expected`